# Magento Stuck During Installation

Tags: centos, installation, php5, magento

I have a very strange problem with Magento installation. The installation is done on EC2 with brand new clean CentOS 6.2 AMIs. PHP version is 5.3.3.

I install PHP with:
yum -y install mysql mysql-server php php-mysql php-gd php-dom php-xml php-pecl-memcached php-pear pcre-devel php-devel  php-mcrypt telnet memcached

During Magento installation, after entering the DB information, Magento will simply get stuck and the browser will not return anything. The spinning will will simply stay there saying connecting to ...

I noticed that the first installation of Magento on each new instance works. The second installation get stuck. Though I do think I had the problem a few times with the first install as well. 
The only solution people have recommended is to use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost for MySQL hostname. That does not help in my case.

Has anybody experienced this kind of behavior? what is this due to? and how do I get rid of it?

I could not find any logs that would point me to the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

can you please turn on the

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

in magento index file and also in your php config file, it will let you know what causes the problem then we can find out the solution.